# Break the String Up

Tags: powershell

When you open the "Run Advertised Programs" from Control Panel you get all the softwares.

I'm trying to display these data using PowerShell.  Here's my code:

```
$tpObject = Get-WmiObject -Namespace ROOT\ccm\Policy\Machine\ActualConfig -Class CCM_SoftwareDistribution | Select-Object -Property PKG_Manufacturer, PKG_Name, PKG_MIFVersion, PRG_ProgramID
$tpObject
```

This will display all the PKG_Manufacturer, PKG_Name, PKG_MIFVersion, PRG_ProgramID
If I was to do this,

```
$tpObject[2]
```

It will only display the third row as 1 whole string.
**My question:** How I break the string up on so I can display the values for 
PKG_Manufacturer PKG_Name PKG_MIFVersion "-" PRG_ProgramID
or
Simply able to access PKG_Manufacturer and PKG_Name

tks

Comment: Boy, get a book and don't go with the answer of one question to the next question with this basic stuff. Stack Overflow is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 1):

If you want just a single property of an object you can either use the `Object.Property` syntax or `Select-Object -ExpandProperty`

This will provide a collection that consists only of property `PKG_Manufacturer` for all of the items of `$tpObject`. Here is an example using the `Object.Property` syntax.

```
$tpObject.PKG_Manufacturer
```

Here is the same effect by expanding with the `Select-Object` parameter `-ExpandProperty` parameter

```
$tpObject | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PKG_Manufacturer
```

These methods can be combined with the array index or filters like `Where-Object` select only certain items of your object array.

```
# Get PKG_Manufacturer for only tpObject[2]
$tpObject[2].PKG_Manufacturer
# or
$tpObject[2] | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PKG_Manufacturer

$tpObject |
    Where-Object {$_.PKG_Manufacturer -eq 'ExampleManufacturer'} |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty PKG_Name
```